# How to do this prismatic/double exposure effect?

Tags: photoshop, exposure, telephoto, editing, double-exposure

[image]

Hello all, just saw this picture on Instagram and was wondering how they got this effect and what the effect is called? Double exposure?

Comment: Hi, Adon, and welcome to Photography at SE! Please see [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3881/15871) and [What's the best way to ask a “How do I achieve this effect?” question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/677/15871) and then please edit the title of your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways one could get results similar to the one in your example image. Among them:

- Use multiple exposures shot at slightly different angles and subject distances (or focal lengths).
- Use special effects lenses in front of the main camera lens, such as a "prismatic lens".
- Use a single exposure and post process it using different layers with slightly different magnification/cropping/tilting applied to that one image.
- Use any combination of the above.

Since the subject's eyes are opened by differing amounts in the example you posted, at least two exposures were used to make that image. Whether they were combined on a single frame of film before being developed, combined by printing two negatives to the same piece of photo paper in a darkroom, combined digitally using a camera with a "double exposure" mode, or outside a camera using post-processing applications, etc. would be very difficult if not impossible to ascertain.

Comment: Another method: if the scene is sufficiently dark, you can set a longer exposure and manually fire a flash twice while the shutter is open.

Comment: @BLHolliday That sounds like you should include it in an answer. Comments here are transitory and subject to deletion at any time. They're also not intended to be used to answer questions. On the other hand, answers that only answer one aspect of the question without being comprehensive and all encompassing are perfectly acceptable.